# How to to run ajax request in loop only on success to go to next loop value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I have a pretty basic scenario: Run 3 Google maps place URLs and show results on every success

This is what I have so far:

```
 var  values = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];

  values.forEach(function(value, i) {

     var jsonReq = JSON.stringify({
        action: 101,
        supported: value 
    });

    ...

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data.ajax.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{
            data:jsonReq
        },
        success:function(data){
           // parse results
           ....

        }
    }); 

  });
```

The problem is I run in loop all 3 URLs **without waiting on success**.

I want to send next request only when get response (callback) from previous one.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: make the requests synchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in complete function in ajax request call next request

```
var  values = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];

  values.forEach(function(value, i) {

     var jsonReq = JSON.stringify({
        action: 101,
        supported: value 
    });

    ...

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data.ajax.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{
            data:jsonReq
        },
        success:function(data){
           // parse results
           ....

        },
      complete: function(){

      }
   }); 

  })
```

Comment: Thanks, And what if you have 200 values?

Comment: async:true,
beforeSend: function () {} in beforesend set i=0 and in complete function set i++

Answer (score 5):

Try recursion instead ... like this

```
var currentR = 0;
    var  values = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
    function sendReqests()
    {
       if(!values[currentR])
       return false;
       var jsonReq = JSON.stringify({
            action: 101,
            supported: values[currentR]
        });
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.ajax.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{
                data:jsonReq
            },
            success:function(data){
             currentR++;  
              if(values[currentR]){
              sendReqests();
              }
            }
        }); 

    }


    // call the recursive function 

    sendReqests();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**setTimeout**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead of using loop

```
var  values = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
var index = 0;

function repeatedCall(value, i) {

     var jsonReq = JSON.stringify({
                        action: 101,
                        supported: values[index]
                    });
     index++;
     if(index == 4)
         clearTimeout(loop );
     else
         setTimeout(repeatedCall, 0);
}
var loop setTimeout(repeatedCall, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instaed of `foreach`, you can use `every` because breaking out of `every` is easier than `foreach`

```
var  values = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
function ajaxCall(value) {
    var jsonReq = JSON.stringify({
        action: 101,
        supported: value 
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data.ajax.php",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false,
        data:{
            data:jsonReq
        },
        success:function(data){
           // parse results
           // if success
           //       return true
           // else
           //       return false

        }
    });
    return true;
}
values.every(ajaxCall);
```